# Nesting a goto loop within a switch

Tags: c++, c

I want to loop over a sequence, but I want to dynamically choose where to start the loop within the sequence. I designed this flow pattern.

```
switch(offset){
    start:
    currentObject = objects[index++]; //a different object is chosen to be manipulated by the sequence of code
    case 0:
        sub_sequence(currentObject); // a sequence that is repeated within the larger sequence of the entire switch
        if(enough_actions) break;
    case 1:
        sub_sequence(currentObject);
        if(enough_actions) break;
    case 2:
        sub_sequence(currentObject);
        if(enough_actions) break;
    goto start;
    }
```

It seems to fit my needs well but I've never seen this design before. Is there anything wrong with this design? Should I be inclined to use an alternative?

Comment: Why not looping over the switch ? You can avoid the goto.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device

Comment: You could just insert this into a `while` loop.

Comment: And yes, `goto` is not the correct construct for a loop, that's what loops are for.

Comment: I think a more accepted way to do that would be to create a loop outside of your switch statement in which your `currentObject` gets incremented and inside of the switch if one of your conditions is satisfied, you can throw a flag that tells it to stop on the next loop.

Also this would allow you to check during the loop increment that you aren't exceeding the bounds of your `objects` array.

Comment: switch/case is in reality a glorified collection of goto statements under the hood, so the design is valid. You'll find this kind of thing in the linux kernel in things like context-switching code. Having said that, many programmers will give you hell for writing code like this :)

Comment: @RichardHodges If you see any occurrence of *Duff's device* in the linux kernel, please submit a patch immediately. Slicing the loop out of the switch statement and thereby "unrolling" *Duff's device* increases both readability **and enables the compiler to perform proper optimizations** which are otherwise blocked by these nasty labels. (Both the explicit `start:` label as well as the `case` labels from the `switch` statement.)

Comment: @Ext3h Well well, I never knew it was called Duff's Device. You learn something new every day. Come to think of it, it has been a few years since I looked through kernel code. I would imagine it's been re-engineered if there is a performance gain in doing so.

Comment: @Ext3h I'd be really interested to hear you elaborate on that. How do labels stop optimization?

Comment: @Ragdoll The compiler has to split the code into different sections whenever it encounters a label. It is no longer able to exchange or merge instructions between these sections, or to apply any other optimizations which would change the behavior of the latter section. In this case, both regular loop optimizations (such as loop unrolling), as well as compiler specific optimizations for handling `switch` statements have been made impossible.

Comment: The mere presence of a label doesn't prevent optimizations, although they sometimes may prevent them. For ex., Gcc has no problems if a `for` loop is replaced by the obvious `if`/`goto` equivalent, to generate the same assembly for them. But I agree with @Ext3h's general claim that Duff's device and similar things don't give better results than what compilers can already do on their own -- loop unrolling is a trivial optimization, and compilers in general know how to do it. Is this question about readability or about optimizations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have constructed there is a *Duff's device*. While it avoids duplicate source code, it is not only difficult to understand for humans, but just as difficult to optimize for the compiler as well.

```
switch(offset)
{
    case 0:
        sub_sequence(currentObject); // a sequence that is repeated within the larger sequence of the entire switch
        if(enough_actions) break;
    case 1:
        sub_sequence(currentObject);
        if(enough_actions) break;
    case 2:
        sub_sequence(currentObject);
        if(enough_actions) break;

        //a different object is chosen to be manipulated by the sequence of code
        currentObject = objects[index++];
        while(true) {
            sub_sequence(currentObject);
            if(enough_actions) break;
            sub_sequence(currentObject);
            if(enough_actions) break;
            sub_sequence(currentObject);
            if(enough_actions) break;
            currentObject = objects[index++];
        }
}
```

By separating the loop from the variable entry point, you are giving the compiler much more freedom to perform optimizations.

In the original code, it was separated by the `start:` label and 3 `case:` labels which force the compiler to treat each code section in between two labels individually.

Without these labels, the compiler may now apply optimizations specific to switch statements to the `switch` block, as well possibly additional loop unrolling or other strategies to the `while` loop.

In the end, going for the more readable variant may yield machine code which is both more compact **and** faster.

This is arguably one of the few cases where "duplicating" code is acceptable, since the `switch` and the `while` block only look similar, but are still behaving entirely different.

**EDIT1:** Moved loop to the end of the switch statement in order to handle `enough_actions` correctly. The loop could have been placed outside the `switch` block if there had been no condition for an early exit.

**BONUS:** Switch free implementation:

```
for(;!enough_actions;offset = 0,currentObject = objects[index++]) {
    for(int i = offset; i < 3 && !enough_actions; i++) {
        sub_sequence(currentObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very helpful post, thank you. The only problem I see is your code does not do the exact same thing as mine. If you break out of the switch, the while loop is still executed and an extra call to sub_sequence() gets done before it can break out of the while. You can avoid this by using goto's instead of breaks in the switch statement, to the end of the while. But I suspect this might cause optimization issues similar to what you pointed out? Is the best choice to do while(!enough_actions)? It's an extra branch but worth it?

Comment: `while(!enough_actions)` is one way to do it. Don't worry about the extra branch, your compiler should take care of that if the condition is simple enough. Using `goto` statements to jump *forward* to a common point is less critical. I would not recommend it though, for the sake of readability. The other option I could recommend, is just to make the execution of the entire while clause conditional. I will use that approach for the edit.

Comment: @Ragdoll Moved loop inside the switch statement now, but at the end. I think that is the cleanest way to express under which condition which instruction is executed.

Answer (score 3):

You could also do:

```
switch(offset)
{
    do
    {
        currentObject = objects[index++]; //a different object is chosen to be manipulated by the sequence of code
        case 0:
            sub_sequence(); // a sequence that is repeated within the larger sequence of the entire switch
            if(enough_actions) break;
        case 1:
            sub_sequence();
            if(enough_actions) break;
        case 2:
            sub_sequence();
            if(enough_actions) break;
    }
    while (1);
}
```

So you avoid the goto ;)
(Where as stated in comment, technically here is no sense to avoid `goto` if this behaving IS needed)

But yeh, you are right, both should fit your needs.

Comment: I really hate, these `while (1) { if (condition) break; }` loops? who is teaching them? a tutorial? what is the point of the loop control condition then? if you are going to do this, better stay with the `goto` since I don't see a lot of difference. The `break` is useful if you happen to suddenly need to stop the loop for an unexpected condition, and honestly I don't remember to have used it in any production code, in any language at all. The new `goto` answer proves that this solution is equivalent to using `goto`.

Comment: @iharob: There isn't even any difference. true. but many people start crying when seeing goto so this is just an alternative way IF you can't avoid it.

Comment: I don't care if people cry when they see a `goto` I am afraid of those people writing programs in fact, because hating `goto` so irrationally is not something a programmer should do. `goto` is useful, just not a good choice for flow control.

Comment: @iharob: I totally aggree.

Comment: @iharob: I certainly agree that `goto` is the cleanest choice more often than some dogmatic programmers would like to think but I hardly see the problem here. There is a loop terminated by breaks, with an idiomatic Duff's device entry which any self-respecting C programmer ought to be able to parse.

Comment: I didn't know this could possibly work.

Comment: @chmike: as stated by doynax, google for "Duff's device" ;) This is standard conform to C.

Comment: @chmike It works for the same reason the OP's construct **does** work. "Duff's device" has one severe drawback though: The compiler will **refuse** to optimize code across labels. Both the `start:` label as well as the `case x:` labels divide the code into sections which the compiler will treat individually. Unroll "Duff's device" to make it more readable and easier to understand for the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I've examined the assembly code produced by Microsoft compilers for the following fibonacci function, and the compiler was still able to slightly modify the unfolded loop sequence (I assume to optimize register dependencies).

```
unsigned int fib(unsigned int n)
{
unsigned int f0, f1;
    f0 = n & 1;         /* if n even, f0=0=fib(0), f1=1=fib(-1) */
    f1 = 1 - f0;        /* else       f1=0=fib(0), f0=1=fib(-1) */
    switch(n%8){
        do{
            f1 += f0;
          case 7:
            f0 += f1;
          case 6:
            f1 += f0;
          case 5:
            f0 += f1;
          case 4:
            f1 += f0;
          case 3:
            f0 += f1;
          case 2:
            f1 += f0;
          case 1:
            f0 += f1;
          case 0:
            continue;
        }while(0 <= (int)(n -= 8));
    }
    return f0;
}
```

Produced assembly code:

```
_fib    PROC                    ; _n$ = eax
        push    esi
        mov     esi, eax
        and     eax, 1
        mov     edx, esi
        mov     ecx, 1
        and     edx, 7
        sub     ecx, eax
        cmp     edx, 7
        ja      SHORT $LN9@fib
        jmp     DWORD PTR $LN17@fib[edx*4]
$LN10@fib:
        sub     esi, 8
        js      SHORT $LN9@fib
        add     ecx, eax
$LN8@fib:
        add     eax, ecx
$LN7@fib:
        add     ecx, eax
$LN6@fib:
        add     eax, ecx
$LN5@fib:
        add     ecx, eax
$LN4@fib:
        add     eax, ecx
$LN3@fib:
        add     ecx, eax
$LN2@fib:
        add     eax, ecx
        jmp     SHORT $LN10@fib
$LN9@fib:
        pop     esi
        ret     0
        npad    1
$LN17@fib:                      ;jump table
        DD      $LN10@fib
        DD      $LN2@fib
        DD      $LN3@fib
        DD      $LN4@fib
        DD      $LN5@fib
        DD      $LN6@fib
        DD      $LN7@fib
        DD      $LN8@fib
_fib    ENDP
```

Perhaps this is more applicable to situations like a linear feed back shift register, where the loop is unfolded to save shifting data between variables. For example:

```
    while(...){
        e = f(a,b,c,d);
        a = b;
        b = c;
        c = d;
        d = e;
    }
```

is unfolded into

```
    do{
        a = f(a,b,c,d);
      case 3:
        b = f(b,c,d,a);
      case 2:
        c = f(c,d,a,b);
      case 1:
        d = f(d,a,b,c);
      case 0:
    }while(...);
```

and if the number of elements isn't a multiple of 4, then Duff's device is used to enter the unfolded loop.

Comment: Why would you say it hasn't been effected? You have forcefully unrolled the loop to a length of 8, disregarding whether this is optimal for the CPU architecture or not. And the compiler has not been able to correct that, as the labels referenced by the jump table prevented it from compacting the loop. Yes, it didn't break, but it clearly deprived the compiler from any chance of optimization.

Comment: @Ext3h - I have yet to see the Microsoft compilers unfold loops. This doesn't mean it never happens, just that I've never see it occur yet. I've also yet to see a compiler optimize a loop sequence like | c = a + b, a = b, b = c | to an unfolded sequence | a += b, b += a |. I could write duplicate code to avoid this, but once familiar with Duff's device, it can be useful, such as a software error correction code encode (parities or syndromes) down the columns of a matrix with an unfolded sequence similar to the fibonacci example, with fixed offsets into the matrix in the unfolded loop.